# getparameter & hide/encode the parameters

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have Pass.jsp page which has javascript and it will send parameters to another page(Data.jsp) with Windows Open Method. Now in the Data.jsp page I am able to get the values & set to the string through getparameter method.

Now my question is is it possible to hide/encode the values which I am passing as parameter and this encoded values has to be decoded in Data.jsp and then it has to be set in Data.jsp page getvalue1 & getvalue1 strings.

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
       String getvalue1= request.getParameter("value1");
       String getvalue2 = request.getParameter("value2");
```

Comment: see this http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-encode-or-decode-url-string-or-form-parameter/ might help you

Comment: could you try with post method.......................